# clustered windows service

Tags: sql-server-2008

I will have a clustered instance of SQL server over two nodes (active/passive) available in my  deployed architecture. I want to deploy a windows service and have it also be active/passive on the two nodes. Is it is as simple as installing the windows service on each node with a startup type of automatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.  Install the service on both nodes. Go into the failover manager (what it's actually named will depend on the OS version that you are using).  Add a new generic service to either the existing group with the SQL Server in it if you want the service to always be on the same machine as the SQL Server, or add a new group and put the service into that new group if the service can run on either machine at any time.